# Managing text and pages using Python

Tags: python, sorting, text

I have code that uses Tkinter, Regex, and datetime modules to take incident report emails from our clients and sorts them by their facility ID (which it writes on each report), and by the date of the incident.

It does this by asking the user to first select a facility file (which has to be organized in a particular way), an incident file (also has a specific pattern, but is essentially a series of emails downloaded into a txt file from our email client), and a blank file to write to.

Everything works, but the problem is that now, I need to be able to write **ONE INCIDENT REPORT PER PAGE** instead of having a continuous block of text.

I have no idea how to do this. All the computers in the office have MS Word, so it would be nice to either write directly to Word with one incident report per page, or find a way to manage content per page in the final text file. If you'd like to see the code that does this whole process, I have posted a link to it below. Thanks!

https://github.com/hillmandj/sort_bot/blob/master/MedTech.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to format your output as HTML. Make your text document look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
hr {
page-break-before: always;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
report 1 text 
here
</pre>
<hr>
<pre>
report 2 
text here
</pre>
<hr>
<pre>
report 
3 text here
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Also save the file with a `.html` extension. When users go to open the file it will open in a web browser (on most computers). Printing from the web browser will start a new page every time `<hr>` appears in the file.

Comment: this is an incredibly good idea. For some reason, when I follow your suggestion, I just get it so that I have multiple incident reports per page, with page breaks. Like this: report (break) report (break) etc. Then when I print, I just get all of the reports again, squished together with lines separating them. Is there something I may be doing wrong? I followed your code exactly, and the html document works when I open it.

Comment: NEVERMIND! added a colon after hr by mistake. GREAT ANSWER!

Comment: One issue I am having -- I now have to format each report in HTML, since it lost all of it's line breaks/paragraphs. I will still give this an answer, since it does solve the underlying problem if formatting wasn't an issue.

Comment: @hillmandj I edited html in the answer to include <pre> blocks around the report text. This will preserve your line breaks exactly as written to file.

Comment: You're awesome, thank you! I've never really worked with HTML before, but I have done some stuff with XML and DTD's -- this just proves to me that I need to keep on studying!

Comment: Having an issue with <> symbols within the alerts, but I learned that the cgi.escape function may be able to help me with this.